# Calling a controller method from a task in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a task in Rails that calls one of my controller methods. I have found similar questions on SO (including one that [nearly asks the exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506896/how-can-i-call-a-controller-action-from-a-rake-task)) but the answer is almost always "move your code to the model."

I don't think that works in my case, but maybe I'm wrong.

I have a method in my controller that fetches some data using Instagram's API, then calls methods in the model to store the data. That seems like a logical separation to me. But now I want to create a task that calls the fetch method in my controller.

1. Is it possible to call the fetch method in my controller from a task?
2. The fetch method can be accessed by a RESTful URL. Can/Should I call that from a task instead?
3. Should my fetch code be moved into my model? If so, why? It doesn't seem directly related to DB activity.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code without putting it on your model: Consider encapsulating any interactions with the Instagram API into a separate class that can then be reused by your controller and your task.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Are you suggesting putting it in a helper class? Can methods from helper classes be called from a task?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a helper.  When I had to do something similar (Rails 2, so possibly slightly out-dated), we added classes to /lib and used them from there, and left helper classes for functionality that would be used directly in views.